# Why is my published website deformed when my unpublished version of the same website perfect?

Tags: html, css

so I have created a webpage using html and css called https://www.printt.us. When I run the code before I publish  it, it looks fine. However, when I publish it, it is completely deformed. This is not a local issue because it affects a lot of other people that have viewed my webpage too. Does anyone know a fix for this?

Comment: Can you share your issue screenshots?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).